# How to insert row in excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to insert row in excel with some categorization.

Below is my input excel

```
Level   Module  STD AREA    MEM_AREA    CM AREA HM AREA TOTAL_AREA  Category
3       Module3     60        10            20             80
```

Total Area is sum of STD_AREA, MEM_AREA, CM_AREA and HM_AREA.
I have to split above row into 2 rows. If any of row is present i need to skip it and add remaining row.

I have to add new rows, 
First row with CM_Area value to HM_Area new column, rest are empty,
Second row with STD_AREA and MEM_AREA to same columns.

Original input:

[image]
Condition to add row :

Next two depth values should be greater than present depth. If next depth value greater than or equal to present depth value we can skip it.

Total Area of Depth 2 is divided into Depth3, Depth4, and so on... But some Area was missed here. I need to add. If condition met, I need to move STD_AREA and MEM_AREA to new row. and TOTAL_AREA is sum of STD_AREA and MEM_AREA.

I have tried below script.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter

ip = "test.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(ip, 'Sheet1') 

def Insert_row(row_number, df, row_value): 
    start_upper = 0 
    end_upper = row_number 
    start_lower = row_number 
    end_lower = df.shape[0] 
    upper_half = [*range(start_upper, end_upper, 1)] 
    lower_half = [*range(start_lower, end_lower, 1)] 
    lower_half = [x.__add__(1) for x in lower_half] 
    index_ = upper_half + lower_half 
    df.index = index_ 
    df.loc[row_number] = row_value 
    df = df.sort_index() 
    return df  

depths = df['Depth'].values.tolist()
for index, value in enumerate(depths):
     if depths[index] < depths[index+1]:
         print (index, value)
         # ADD new row here with STD_AREA and MEM_AREA.

#row_value = [4,Module4, , , , 10, 10, 'category']
#Insert_row(1, df, row_value)

#row_value = [4,Module5,60, 10, 10,  , 'category']
#Insert_row(1, df, row_value)
```

Expected output :

```
Level   Module  STD AREA    MEM_AREA   CM AREA  HM AREA  TOTAL_AREA Category
4       Module4                                       20    20   Category1
4       Module4    60             10                        70   Category2
```

Expected Output:
[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to add two rows, you should better to create a dicionary with the keys as the column name and lists as values and append this new dataframe to the read one.

With code it gives:

```py
import pandas as pd
ip = "test.xlsx"
read_df = pd.read_excel(ip, 'Sheet1') 

to_append_df = pd.Dataframe(
    {
        'Level': [4, 4],
        'Module': ['Module4', 'Module5'],
        'STD AREA': [float('NaN'), 60.0],
        'MEM AREA': [float('NaN'), 10.0],
        'HM AREA': [20, float('NaN')],
        'TOTAL AREA': [20, 70],
        'Category': ['Category1', 'Category2'],
    }
)

new_df = pd.concat([read_dataframe, to_append_df])
```

This prints:

```
   CM AREA   Category  HM AREA  Level  MEM AREA   Module  STD AREA  TOTAL AREA
0     20.0        NaN      NaN      3      10.0  Module3      60.0          80
1      NaN  Category1     20.0      4       NaN  Module4       NaN          20
2      NaN  Category2      NaN      4      10.0  Module5      60.0          70
```

I use `float('NaN')` in order to have a cell with a undefined value.

Comment: My data has more than 5,000 rows, i need to find specific condition to add rows and add required Columns automatically. So, Instead of passing values, it is better to pass cell values using column name.

Comment: You should do the other way. Read everything and then delete the extra rows and columns. What are the conditions?